# Pushforward measure with inverse function.

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the definition of the pushforward of a measure $\mu$ under a function $f$:
$$
f_\sharp\mu(A) := \mu(f^{-1}(A)). 
$$

Now consider the pushforward of the inverse of $f$, i.e., the quantity
$$
{f^{-1}}_\sharp\mu(A) := \mu(f(A)).
$$

I am wondering whether this makes sense at all. For example, if $f$ is not injective, then $f^{-1}$ is not a function but rather a relation (or set-valued mapping). But the pushforward is usually only defined for single-valued mappings. But the right-hand side is the inverse of the relation $(f^{-1})^{-1}(A) = f(A)$, which is the original function again so it should be well defined.

So my question is: does it make sense to consider the pushforward of an inverse, in cases where $f$ is not injective? Does it have a name? pushbackward measure?

Finally, $f\sharp$ is a linear operator between measures, so is there a relation between $f{^{-1}}_\sharp$ and the inverse linear operator $(f_\sharp)^{-1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is  a measurable function then $f^{-1}(A)$ is  measurable whenever $A$ is measurable so $\mu (f^{-1}(A))$ makes sense. Even if $f$ is an injective measurable function there is no guarantee that $f(A)$ is measurable. If we assume that $f(A)$ is measurable for every measurable set $A$ we can consider $\mu (f(A))$ but countable additivity requires that $f(A_n)$'s is disjoint if $A_n$'s are disjoint. This requires injectivity. So we can consider $\mu (f(A))$ as  measure if $f$ is injective and maps measurable sets to measurable sets.